# A question on the consistency of a (seemingly) very weak set theory

Tags: lo.logic, set-theory

I have preoccupied myself some with very weak set theories that suffice to interpret Robinson Arithmetic, as in this question [Is Extensionality needed for the incompleteness of very weak set theories?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/222125/is-extensionality-needed-for-the-incompleteness-of-very-weak-set-theories). May we have confidence that the theory SU, which has the axioms for empty set and for universal set and for adjunction as well as the rules $\vdash\hspace{-2pt}\alpha(a)\Leftrightarrow\hspace{2pt}\vdash\hspace{-2pt} a\notin\{x|\lnot\alpha(x)\}$ and $\vdash\hspace{-2pt}\alpha(a)\Leftrightarrow\hspace{2pt}\vdash\hspace{-2pt} a\in\{x|\alpha(x)\}$ is consistent or even omega consistent in an appropriate sense? Does SU still support its own coding to get a Godelian provability predicate for SU?

SU has all set terms and we presuppose an underlying theory of identity by having the Leibnizian-Russellian definition of $a=b$ as $\forall u(a\in u\rightarrow b\in u)$ and the axiom schema $\vdash\forall x, y(x=y\rightarrow(\alpha(x)\rightarrow\alpha(y)))$.

P.S. The appropriate omega consistency I want is that if $\vdash\alpha(t)$ for all terms $t$ then $\nvdash\exists x\lnot\alpha(x)$.

Comment: I don't quite understand the additional axiom in SU - is "$\{x: \neg \alpha(x)\}$" actually a term in your language? If not, what exactly is it shorthand for? (For example, are you saying that there **is** a set of all $x$ such that $\neg\alpha(x)$?) Also, what assumptions are you willing to make - e.g. if SU is consistent *relative to ZFC*, are you happy?

Comment: The addition you are alluding to comprise inference rules and not axioms. Yes, $\{x|\lnot\alpha(x)\}$ is a term. In fact, all terms $\{x|\alpha(x)\}$ are terms of SU. I would believe that SU is consistent relative to much weaker theories than $ZFC$, but any result is of interest.

Comment: OK, then I am worried your theory is inconsistent: you have a term $\{x: \neg (x\in x)\}$! Now, you don't have an axiom scheme saying $\forall x[\alpha(x)\iff x\in \{x: \alpha(x)\}]$, so we don't immediately hit a contradiction - but at this point I wouldn't be surprised if there is a contradiction.

Comment: Of course I do not have that axiom schema, and I fail to understand why you would not be surprised if SU is inconsistent.

Comment: May terms $\lbrace x \mid \alpha(x) \rbrace$  contain parameters?

Comment: I think the worry about inconsistency comes from the fact that changing your inference rule to the axiom $\forall a . (\alpha(a) \Leftrightarrow a \not\in \lbrace x \mid \lnot \alpha(x) \rbrace)$ opens the road to Russell's paradox.

Comment: I had, for a peculiar reason, thought that I should need only closed set terms; so I do not allow parameters. Inconsistency arises immediately if the rules are changed into axioms.

Comment: Is there any reason we can't just have $\{x: \alpha(x)\}$ be the emptyset for every formula $\alpha$? If not, do you *really* not want any other rules governing such terms?

Comment: SU has adjunction, so e.g. $\forall x(x\in\{y|y\in\emptyset\vee y=\emptyset\}\leftrightarrow (x\in\emptyset\vee x=\emptyset))$ is an axiom.

So the system cannot be interpreted in such a way as you suggest.

Comment: Aside from that, it seems that I may want some further principles to get this to do the work I want.

Comment: In the penultimate comment above I presuppose that SU has an underlying identity theory at its disposal.

Comment: For the record, the further principle I seem to need is the existence of a universal set. In the interest of purity, the identity theory I want to presuppose is given by the Leibnizian-Russellian definition of $a=b$ as $\forall u(a\in u\rightarrow b\in u)$ and thence the schema $\vdash a=b\rightarrow (\alpha(a)\rightarrow\alpha(b))$.

Comment: @Andrej Bauer I added some in an update.

Comment: @Noah Schweber I added some in an update.

Comment: I’m not sure how much this will help, but I encountered an inconsistency in a theory with a universal set, which had a couple of commonalities with yours, in my own work.  I’ve got a proof schema in my forthcoming _Logique et Analyse_ article; unabridged preprint at http://www.logic-center.be/Publications/Bibliotheque/SheridanVariantChurch.pdf §19.2.  Adjunction is not used in the proof, but was part of the original motivation (footnote 7, p. 8, and p. 23.)

Comment: Thanks. In $19.2 you use principles way stronger than those offered by SU.